# jQuery on file upload check if file type is PDF and add in new input

Tags: jquery

I'm working in a Rails application and I want to conditionally apply a file upload field based on the existence of a previous input.

In this case if a user tries to upload a PDF file another file field presents itself to upload a placeholder image.

I'm a relative newb with jQuery and thus I have the following that will notice a change affect on the input field.

```
$("input[type=file]").on('change', function(){
  {alert(this.files[0].name);
  }
})
```

What I'm struggling with is how to have jQuery parse out and look for pdf files. I'm pretty sure I can figure out appending if PDF present with the form. How do I check the file upload for a specific file type of PDF?

I've also gone so far with:

```
$("input[type=file]").on('change', function(){
  var fileExtension = 'pdf';
  if ($.contains($(this).val().split('.'), fileExtension) > 0){
    alert('Huzzah');
  }
})
```

This does nothing. I get no errors but there's no alert when used in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At minimum you can check the `type` property as you iterate over the selected files. The type you want to look for PDF's is `application/pdf`.

For true MIME types you'll want to use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) to evaluate the file(s). But that's another can of worms.

Try selecting a PDF file in this snippet...

```js
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function() {
  Object.values(this.files).forEach(function(file) {
    console.log(`Type: ${file.type}`);
    if (file.type == 'application/pdf') {
      console.log('Huzzah!')
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple>
```

Comment: How do i get file.temp_name to move in php? Thanks

Comment: I know how to do it, but when I execute the code it tells me that $ _FILES ['temp_name'] not exist :( . What is the correct way to send it to PHP to process it?  Thanks

Comment: It’s usually found at `$_FILES['name_of_your_input']['tmp_name']`